# How to restart ZFS?

Tags: linux, services, zfs

I am using ZFS and zpool, however it is locked up on a faulty drive. Without restarting the machine (it is a server) how can ZFS be force restarted?

OS: CentOS 7 Linux

Comment: Solaris? Linux?

Comment: CentOS 7, Linux

Comment: Can you `zpool export` the pool?

Comment: What's the output of `zpool status` so we can have an idea?

Comment: The output of `zpool status` varies, sometimes showing no errors at all, sometimes showing some evidence of corruption (errors), sometimes being locked to I/O, at which point any command beginning with `zpool ...` hangs indefinitely.

Comment: I have attempted to `export` the pool, though it says it cannot unmount. Force kill on the smbd processes that have open file handles does nothing, and `zpool clear ...` has hung. the pool is locked for I/O right now.